# Checkbox not working on mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2011

I wrote an excel VBA macro that works with checkboxes. To check whether the checkbox is selected or not I use the following code:

```
Sheet4.Shapes("dietary").OLEFormat.Object.Value
```

This works well on a windows PC; however, a colleague uses a mac and there it produces an error.

How can I use the checkboxes in a way that is compatible with windows and mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the Checkbox. It is with the way you are referencing the sheet :)

Codenames sometimes give a problem in Excel 2011

Try this

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Shapes("dietary").OLEFormat.Object.Value
```

**Example (Depicting Both Scenarios)**

[image]

Now removing the CodeName

[image]